# Java MongoDB just saving ID

Tags: java, mongodb, document, nosql

For some reason, my Mongo DB is just creating just an ID belonging the documents, and not the rest of the attributes.

I've got a Spring @Repository:

```
@Repository
public class BeerRepository {

    public void createBeer(final BeerDTO beerDTO) {

        Mongo mongo = new Mongo("localhost", 27017);
        DB db = mongo.getDB("beers");

        DBCollection beerCollection = db.getCollection(BeerDTO.COLLECTION_NAME);

        beerCollection.insert(beerDTO);
//        System.err.println(beerCollection.findOne());
    }
}
```

And a simple POJO, nothing else:

```
@Document
public class BeerDTO extends BasicDBObject {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1235041607375829595L;
    public static final String COLLECTION_NAME = "Beers";

    @Field("id")
    private String id;

    @Field("name")
    private String name;

    @Field("abv")
    private int abv; //alcohol by volume

    public BeerDTO(String id, String name, int abv) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.abv = abv;
    }
```

}

However, this is the only thing Mongo is getting:

[image]

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Maybe It can be obvious for you but, did you set all fields for beerDTO before to insert it? And those fields are not null?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but indeed, that was the first thing I checked. The DTO contains data.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the approach for createBeer in the repo and it worked:

```
public void createBeer(final BeerDTO beerDTO) {

        MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient();
        DB database = mongoClient.getDB("beers");
        DBCollection beerCollection = database.getCollection(BeerDTO.COLLECTION_NAME);

        DBObject beer = new BasicDBObject("id", beerDTO.getId())
                .append("name", beerDTO.getName())
                .append("abv", beerDTO.getAbv());

        beerCollection.insert(beer);
    }
```